# Mean-cli configuration issue

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am new to mean based app development .I am following the [here](http://learn.mean.io) to configure the app i have installed all the prerequisites as mentioned in the link but getting error while executing the working on windows 7

```
npm install -g mean-cli
```

Error[image]

Comment: I am not windows user, but it seems you need to install this package:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: @SemihGk.thanks for the response but Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86) is already installed and no luck still getting the same error

Comment: It has been long time I havent used windows. Sorry, I can not help you, but I would reinstall different versions of that packages ( if you use visuall studio, remove it before reinstall again. sometimes its files conflict.). Hope you can figure out. Good luck!

Comment: @SemihGk. Thanks for putting your comments which helped my in finding the solution I updated the C++ templates and VS and my issue got resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed and updated the Visual Studio C++ template which got the issue fixed